# Copy and Repeat Code Breaks After Row 488

Tags: excel, vba

For some reason after cell 488 the function stops copying correctly. After 488 all the way to the end (about row 1,000) it pulls from the same cell all the way to the bottom.

Any way to make this code more robust so that it will always pull from the cell in the same row?

If I need to clarify please let me know, i would be happy to elaborate however necessary.

```
Sub Compare()
    Dim lastRow As Long

    With Sheets("MP Parameters")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).row
        Range("A1").EntireColumn.Insert
        With .Range("A5:A" & lastRow)
            .Formula = "=MID(B5,FIND(""¬"",SUBSTITUTE(B5,""-"",""¬"",3))+1,LEN(B5))"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As cyboashu stated you are converting before calculation is completed which is causing the problem.

However you are first placing the `Formula` to the `Cell` and then copying the `Value` into the `Cell`. This can be shortened to letting VBA calculate the `Value` and place it into the `Cell`.

```
Sub Compare()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim cell As Range

    With Worksheets("MP Parameters")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        Range("A1").EntireColumn.Insert
        For Each cell In .Range("A5:A" & lastRow)
            cell.Value = Mid(cell.Offset(0, 1), Application.WorksheetFunction.Find _
                         ("¬", Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(cell.Offset _
                         (0, 1), "-", "¬", 3)) + 1, Len(cell.Offset(0, 1)))
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

The functionality of the above code is tested and works.

Comment: It seems as though there is a seemingly strange error in which the cells are blank. It doesn't through an error message, but it seems as though perhaps the for condition is not met in this case in some way to do nothing yet throw no error code. It might be an issue on my end I will look into it

Comment: Scratch that, was my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are converting to value before calculation completed.

```
Sub Compare()
    Dim lastRow As Long

    With Sheets("MP Parameters")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        Range("A1").EntireColumn.Insert
        With .Range("A5:A" & lastRow)
            .Formula = "=MID(B5,FIND(""¬"",SUBSTITUTE(B5,""-"",""¬"",3))+1,LEN(B5))"

            '/ Force calculation before cobnversting to value
            Sheets("MP Parameters").Calculate
            Do
            Loop Until Application.CalculationState = xlDone

            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: So i see what you mean, this is certainly going to work better, but for some reason it is still not great for me. The same issue is occuring. I'm going to restart excel just in case.

Comment: Confirmed, after restart the problem still persists

Comment: comment out the .Value= .Value part, rerun and see what happens.