# Insert formulas (range) then copy>paste values only

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I want to make a macro that copies formulas into the range `Q6:Q2500`. After the macro inserted the formulas it should copy>paste values only.

```
[...]
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Range("Q6").Formula = "=IF(INDIRECT(""A""&ROW())="""","""",CONCATENATE(INDIRECT(""A""&ROW()),""/"",INDIRECT(""B""&ROW()),""/"",INDIRECT(""E""&ROW()),""/"",INDIRECT(""P""&ROW())))"
Range("Q6").Copy
Range("Q6:Q2500").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
Range("Q6:Q2500").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

When I run this macro it inserts the formulas as intended. But when I try to paste values only I get the first value repeated till `Q2500`. I think it's because the formula update is to slow.

I saw another thread on Stack but the answer was to convert the formula into a VBA function. I don't know how to convert this formula.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy and Repeat Code Breaks After Row 488](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38731026/copy-and-repeat-code-breaks-after-row-488), see this question and anwser

Comment: Thanks for the link. I inserted a force calculation line (second answer) but it doesn't work for me... Also I don't know how to convert this formula into VBA (first answer).

Comment: I'll post the Formula conversion in a minute

Comment: See my answer for the conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting before calculation is completed which is causing the problem.

However you are first placing the `Formula` to the `Cell` and then copying the `Value` into the `Cell`. This can be shortened to letting VBA calculate the `Value` and place it into the `Cell`. Its advised to not make use of `.Copy` and `.Paste` if it can be avoided.

See example:

```
Sub JoinStrings()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim strJoin As String

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For Each cell In .Range("Q6:Q2500")
            If .Range(cell.Offset(0, -16).Value) <> "" Then
                strJoin = .Range(cell.Offset(0, -16).Value).Value & "/"
                strJoin = strJoin & .Range(cell.Offset(0, -15).Value).Value & "/"
                strJoin = strJoin & .Range(cell.Offset(0, -12).Value).Value & "/"
                strJoin = strJoin & .Range(cell.Offset(0, -1).Value).Value
                cell.Value = strJoin
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You paste the content of `Q6` twice instead of copying the values of the whole column.

```
Range("Q6").Formula = "=IF(INDIRECT(""A""&ROW())="""","""",CONCATENATE(INDIRECT(""A""&ROW()),""/"",INDIRECT(""B""&ROW()),""/"",INDIRECT(""E""&ROW()),""/"",INDIRECT(""P""&ROW())))"
Range("Q6").Copy
Range("Q6:Q2500").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)

If Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
    Range("Q6:Q2500").Copy
    Range("Q6:Q2500").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
```

Comment: Hi Tom, nice find! I think this will solve **ONE** problem. But now I have another problem. Excel still calculates the formulas too slow. Every line is **0** now.

Comment: Does your formula work, when you put it in a cell by hand?

Comment: Yes, and it also works if I delete the `Range("Q6:Q2500").Copy
Range("Q6:Q2500").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` line. But I need values only.

Comment: Works! Thank you! After inserting the corrected formula it did not work. I had to restard Excel..................

Answer (score 1):

For anyone searching this. In general to value paste efficiently use the below code.

```
With Selection
.Value = .Value
End With
```